# SyntaxError - SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1 - Ionic

Tags: json, ionic-framework

When I push my data to my database, I get back a problem with my JSON:

```
1
<br/>mail@mail.comhere{"userData": {"user_id":"21","name":"eman","email":"mail@mail.com","username":"username_name","token":"6de6b72ad590562b566675f6f780cb26cf67dc46e73cf025ad5ef7da92735b45"}}
```

Seems I get back html and not JSON data, the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Response.Body.json (http://localhost:8106/build/vendor.js:71523:25)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (http://localhost:8106/build/main.js:757:29)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (http://localhost:8106/build/vendor.js:38232:16)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (http://localhost:8106/build/vendor.js:38179:22)
    at Subscriber._next (http://localhost:8106/build/vendor.js:38119:26)
    at Subscriber.next (http://localhost:8106/build/vendor.js:38083:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:8106/build/vendor.js:72016:38)
    at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8106/build/polyfills.js:3:15660)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:8106/build/vendor.js:4974:33)
```

Here is my API Code:

```
postData(credentials, type){

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
      let headers = new Headers();
      this.http.post(apiUrl+type, JSON.stringify(credentials), {headers: headers}).
      subscribe(res =>{
        resolve(res.json());
      }, (err) =>{
        reject(err);
      });
```

I spent whole day trying to find a solution, check every post on SO but still can not find solution. It may be a duplicate post but honestly I did not see the answer on other posts.

--edit--
webapi

```
<?php
require 'config.php';
require 'Slim/Slim.php';

\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->post('/login','login'); /* User login */
$app->post('/signup','signup'); /* User Signup  */
$app->get('/getFeed','getFeed'); /* User Feeds  */
$app->post('/feed','feed'); /* User Feeds  */
$app->post('/feedUpdate','feedUpdate'); /* User Feeds  */
$app->post('/feedDelete','feedDelete'); /* User Feeds  */
$app->post('/getImages', 'getImages');


$app->run();

/************************* USER LOGIN *************************************/
/* ### User login ### */
function login() {

    $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $data = json_decode($request->getBody());

    try {

        $db = getDB();
        $userData ='';
        $sql = "SELECT user_id, name, email, username FROM users WHERE (username=:username or email=:username) and password=:password ";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam("username", $data->username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $password=hash('sha256',$data->password);
        $stmt->bindParam("password", $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $mainCount=$stmt->rowCount();
        $userData = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        if(!empty($userData))
        {
            $user_id=$userData->user_id;
            $userData->token = apiToken($user_id);
        }

        $db = null;
         if($userData){
               $userData = json_encode($userData);
                echo '{"userData": ' .$userData . '}';
            } else {
               echo '{"error":{"text":"Bad request wrong username and password"}}';
            }


    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
    }
}


/* ### User registration ### */
function signup() {
    $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $data = json_decode($request->getBody());
    $email=$data->email;
    $name=$data->name;
    $username=$data->username;
    $password=$data->password;

    try {

        $username_check = preg_match('~^[A-Za-z0-9_]{3,20}$~i', $username);
        $email_check = preg_match('~^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.([a-zA-Z]{2,4})$~i', $email);
        $password_check = preg_match('~^[A-Za-z0-9!@#$%^&*()_]{6,20}$~i', $password);

        echo $email_check.'<br/>'.$email;

        if (strlen(trim($username))>0 && strlen(trim($password))>0 && strlen(trim($email))>0 && $email_check>0 && $username_check>0 && $password_check>0)
        {
            echo 'here';
            $db = getDB();
            $userData = '';
            $sql = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username=:username or email=:email";
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam("username", $username,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam("email", $email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();
            $mainCount=$stmt->rowCount();
            $created=time();
            if($mainCount==0)
            {

                /*Inserting user values*/
                $sql1="INSERT INTO users(username,password,email,name)VALUES(:username,:password,:email,:name)";
                $stmt1 = $db->prepare($sql1);
                $stmt1->bindParam("username", $username,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $password=hash('sha256',$data->password);
                $stmt1->bindParam("password", $password,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt1->bindParam("email", $email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt1->bindParam("name", $name,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt1->execute();

                $userData=internalUserDetails($email);

            }

            $db = null;

            if($userData){
               $userData = json_encode($userData);
                echo '{"userData": ' .$userData . '}';
            } else {
               echo '{"error":{"text":"Enter valid data"}}';
            }

        }
        else{
            echo '{"error":{"text":"Enter valid data"}}';
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
    }
}
function email() {
    $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $data = json_decode($request->getBody());
    $email=$data->email;
    try {

        $email_check = preg_match('~^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.([a-zA-Z]{2,4})$~i', $email);

        if (strlen(trim($email))>0 && $email_check>0)
        {
            $db = getDB();
            $userData = '';
            $sql = "SELECT user_id FROM emailUsers WHERE email=:email";
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam("email", $email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();
            $mainCount=$stmt->rowCount();
            $created=time();
            if($mainCount==0)
            {

                /*Inserting user values*/
                $sql1="INSERT INTO emailUsers(email)VALUES(:email)";
                $stmt1 = $db->prepare($sql1);
                $stmt1->bindParam("email", $email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt1->execute();


            }
            $userData=internalEmailDetails($email);
            $db = null;
            if($userData){
               $userData = json_encode($userData);
                echo '{"userData": ' .$userData . '}';
            } else {
               echo '{"error":{"text":"Enter valid dataaaa"}}';
            }
        }
        else{
            echo '{"error":{"text":"Enter valid data"}}';
        }
    }

    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
    }
}
/* ### internal Username Details ### */
function internalUserDetails($input) {

    try {
        $db = getDB();
        $sql = "SELECT user_id, name, email, username FROM users WHERE username=:input or email=:input";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam("input", $input,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $usernameDetails = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $usernameDetails->token = apiToken($usernameDetails->user_id);
        $db = null;
        return $usernameDetails;

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
    }

}

function getFeed(){


    try {

        if(1){
            $feedData = '';
            $db = getDB();

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM feed  ORDER BY feed_id DESC LIMIT 15";
                $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->bindParam("user_id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $stmt->bindParam("lastCreated", $lastCreated, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            $stmt->execute();
            $feedData = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

            $db = null;

            if($feedData)
            echo '{"feedData": ' . json_encode($feedData) . '}';
            else
            echo '{"feedData": ""}';
        } else{
            echo '{"error":{"text":"No access"}}';
        }

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
    }

}

function feed(){
    $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $data = json_decode($request->getBody());
    $user_id=$data->user_id;
    $token=$data->token;
    $lastCreated = $data->lastCreated;
    $systemToken=apiToken($user_id);

    try {

        if($systemToken == $token){
            $feedData = '';
            $db = getDB();
            if($lastCreated){
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM feed WHERE user_id_fk=:user_id AND created < :lastCreated ORDER BY feed_id DESC LIMIT 5";
                $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->bindParam("user_id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $stmt->bindParam("lastCreated", $lastCreated, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            }
            else{
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM feed WHERE user_id_fk=:user_id ORDER BY feed_id DESC LIMIT 5";
                $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->bindParam("user_id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            }
            $stmt->execute();
            $feedData = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

            $db = null;

            if($feedData)
            echo '{"feedData": ' . json_encode($feedData) . '}';
            else
            echo '{"feedData": ""}';
        } else{
            echo '{"error":{"text":"No access"}}';
        }

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
    }

}

function feedUpdate(){

    $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $data = json_decode($request->getBody());
    $user_id=$data->user_id;
    $token=$data->token;
    $feed=$data->feed;

    $systemToken=apiToken($user_id);

    try {

        if($systemToken == $token){


            $feedData = '';
            $db = getDB();
            $sql = "INSERT INTO feed ( feed, created, user_id_fk) VALUES (:feed,:created,:user_id)";
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam("feed", $feed, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam("user_id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $created = time();
            $stmt->bindParam("created", $created, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();



            $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM feed WHERE user_id_fk=:user_id ORDER BY feed_id DESC LIMIT 1";
            $stmt1 = $db->prepare($sql1);
            $stmt1->bindParam("user_id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt1->execute();
            $feedData = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);


            $db = null;
            echo '{"feedData": ' . json_encode($feedData) . '}';
        } else{
            echo '{"error":{"text":"No access"}}';
        }

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
    }

}



function feedDelete(){
    $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $data = json_decode($request->getBody());
    $user_id=$data->user_id;
    $token=$data->token;
    $feed_id=$data->feed_id;

    $systemToken=apiToken($user_id);

    try {

        if($systemToken == $token){
            $feedData = '';
            $db = getDB();
            $sql = "Delete FROM feed WHERE user_id_fk=:user_id AND feed_id=:feed_id";
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam("user_id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam("feed_id", $feed_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();


            $db = null;
            echo '{"success":{"text":"Feed deleted"}}';
        } else{
            echo '{"error":{"text":"No access"}}';
        }

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
    }   

}
$app->post('/userImage','userImage'); /* User Details */
function userImage(){
    $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $data = json_decode($request->getBody());
    $user_id=$data->user_id;
    $token=$data->token;
    $imageB64=$data->imageB64;
    $systemToken=apiToken($user_id);
    try {
        if(1){
            $db = getDB();
            $sql = "INSERT INTO imagesData(b64,user_id_fk) VALUES(:b64,:user_id)";
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam("user_id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam("b64", $imageB64, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();
            $db = null;
            echo '{"success":{"status":"uploaded"}}';
        } else{
            echo '{"error":{"text":"No access"}}';
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
    }
}

$app->post('/getImages', 'getImages');
function getImages(){
    $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $data = json_decode($request->getBody());
    $user_id=$data->user_id;
    $token=$data->token;

    $systemToken=apiToken($user_id);
    try {
        if(1){
            $db = getDB();
            $sql = "SELECT b64 FROM imagesData";
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

            $stmt->execute();
            $imageData = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $db = null;
            echo '{"imageData": ' . json_encode($imageData) . '}';
        } else{
            echo '{"error":{"text":"No access"}}';
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: why this => `<br/>mail@mail.comhere`  getting in ressponse, check your api response check weather is it returns valid json?

Comment: @Onkar that is the response I get from json. I don't know why I get this <br/>mail before my json. It go well into my database

Comment: this response creates error while resolving json   `resolve(res.json());` , its cause to error

Comment: @Onkar any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: check your web api, problem is in web api  response.

Comment: @Onkar I edited the post with the webapi on it. any chance you could help?

Comment: echo $email_check.'<br/>'.$email;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in signUp() function, two times unwanted echo are there,

```
        echo $email_check.'<br/>'.$email;              // remove this unwanted stuff

        if (strlen(trim($username))>0 && strlen(trim($password))>0 && strlen(trim($email))>0 && $email_check>0 && $username_check>0 && $password_check>0)
        {
            echo 'here';            // remove this unwanted stuff
        ....
```

`echo $email_check.'<br/>'.$email;`       remove this unwanted stuff

`echo 'here';`                            remove this unwanted stuff

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know if this is related but now I get another problem which is vendor.js:1704 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'user_id' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'user_id' of undefined

Comment: @ChinaXiaoHong this is typescript problem, check your code, its not related to this question

Answer (score 1):

In your signup function you have to remove this line:

```
echo $email_check.'<br/>'.$email;
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this problem by removing platform (i.e. ionic platform rm android ). And add platform (i.e. ionic platform add android ) again.